# CMOS INVERTER basics

Tags: electricity

in brief, what's confusing me: whenever the transistor is ON, when I can say it's acting like idea switch? for example why when at cmos inverter if vin=5v then we say the output is 0 instantly, why? I know the NMOS switch is conducting at vin=5v and there's a path between "grand" to "output" but who said that NMOS switch in that case is like idea switch "shorted" ?! 
[image]
Moreover, whenever PMOS and NMOS are conducting altogether then we aren't saying that output is 0v or 5v why?! .. what's exactly confusing me is when vin=vdd then we say that NMOS is shorted and PMOS IS OFF, who said that NMOS is shorted? is that because we feed it by vin=5v which he gets the maximum voltage then I assume that switch is act like shorted?

*** lets assume I have capacitor at Vout (OUT)

Comment: Saying "the transistor" implies a schematic -- which I do not see in your question.  Could you please post a schematic of the circuit that you are referring to.

Comment: The transistor is controlled by the voltage between gate and source. For the low-side NMOS, the source is connected to VSS (or GND... same thing for our purposes). So whenever the gate of the NMOS is above oh, around 2V or something, it will turn on and conduct between drain (output) and source (ground). That is just how MOSFET's behave. PMOS is similar, but the gate to source voltage must be negative to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, in digital logic, transistors sometimes can be seen as ideal switches to simplify things. When Vin = 5v, the NMOS is creating a path for the output to be connected to the ground. It is also causing the PMOS to act like an open switch and not connect the output to anything. The opposite occurs when Vin = 0v. The PMOS connects the output to the high voltage and the NMOS acts like an open switch. Thus the circuit cause Vout to be the inverse of Vin.

Answer (score 0):

Using long-channel devices, the "resistance" will be about K/2 * W/L * (Vgs-Vt)

Thus the FETs are never shorts.

And how fast? The channels require time to form, even after the gate voltage starts to encourage charge to move from elsewhere and gather under the gate-oxide.

If substrate ties are far away, then channel-formation will be slow.